# What is the difference between a Servlet Filter and a Servlet Context Listener?

Tags: jsf, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

What are the differences between using a Servlet Filter versus a Servlet Context Listener?

When would you use one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) intercepts on HTTP requests matching its URL pattern and allows you to modify them. See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

> A filter is an object that performs filtering tasks on either the request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the response from a resource, or both.
>
> Filters perform filtering in the `doFilter` method. Every `Filter` has access to a `FilterConfig` object from which it can obtain its initialization parameters, and a reference to the `ServletContext` which it can use, for example, to load resources needed for filtering tasks.
>
> Filters are configured in the deployment descriptor of a web application.
>
> Examples that have been identified for this design are:
>
> - Authentication Filters
> - Logging and Auditing Filters
> - Image conversion Filters
> - Data compression Filters
> - Encryption Filters
> - Tokenizing Filters
> - Filters that trigger resource access events
> - XSL/T filters
> - Mime-type chain Filter

A [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) intercepts on webapp's startup and shutdown and allows you to execute some code on startup and/or shutdown. See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html):

> Interface for receiving notification events about `ServletContext` lifecycle changes.
>
> In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with `WebListener`, or registered via one of the `addListener` methods defined on `ServletContext`.
>
> Implementations of this interface are invoked at their `contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)` method in the order in which they have been declared, and at their `contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)` method in reverse order.

When to use the one or the other should now be obvious. Use a `Filter` if you want to intercept on HTTP requests maching a specific URL pattern because you want to check/modify the HTTP request/response. Use a `ServletContextListener` if you want to intercept on webapp's startup and/or shutdown.

Please know where to find the javadocs and how to interpret them. They contain all answers to this kind of trivial questions.

Comment: You provided a lot more useful information than can be found in the java docs. So thanks.