# How to hit a servlet class with ServletContextListener from Jsp page button click

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I have a servlet implementing ServletContextListener.Now as per my need i have to send some parameters from jsp page submit button click to this servlet but it is not hitting the servlet file on submit button click..

Here is my Servlet code..

```
@WebListener()
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener {

Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(

            Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 00);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    timer.schedule(
            new MyTask(),
            date.getTime(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

}

And here is my JSP page..

```
<form action="/MyContext/" method="GET">
        <label>Set Date: </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Set Time: </label>
        <input type="text" name="time" id="time">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is my web.xml file ..

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyContext</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyContext</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyContext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyContext</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listner>
    <listner-class>
 MyContext
    </listner-class>>
</listner>>
```

Please guys help me ..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please read "Head First JSP and Servlets", without knowing basic behavior of web container and its related components it would be very difficult to achieve what you need. Please read the basics of servlet. Then it will be easy for you to program using frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

The class **MyContext** implementing ServletContextListener  is not a Servlet that process your requests. 
**Listeners** wait for some events to happen and gives us a handlers method to handle the event. In the case of ServletContextListener we can handle the initialization and destruction of the ServletContext.
Refer this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812664/what-is-the-difference-between-a-servlet-filter-and-a-servlet-context-listener) to get a better understanding.